# Referencing and manipulating params after form submit in Rails 4 -- ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails 4, we have to change to strong parameters. I haven't figured out how to reference specific parameters yet. I keep running into this error:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in TransactionsController#create
```

When a Transaction is created, I want to manipulate some of the parameters before creating that new object. I also want to save the id of the `Account` (sent in the form as a `hidden_field_tag`).

Here is my form:

```
#newTransaction-modal.modal.hide.fade style="display: none;"
  h3 New Transaction
  = form_for Transaction.new do |f|
    p Date:
    = f.text_field :transaction_date, value: Time.now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") 
    p Payee: 
    = f.text_field :payee
    p Category: 
    = f.select :category, options_for_select(["Phone", "Restaurants", "Gas/Fuel"])
    p Memo: 
    = f.text_field :memo
    p Outflow: 
    = f.text_field :outflow, value: 0
    p Inflow:
    = f.text_field :inflow, value: 0
    = hidden_field_tag :account_id, value: params[:id]
    br
    a.btn href="#"  data-dismiss="modal" Cancel

    = f.submit "Create Transaction", class: "btn"
```

and my Transactions controller:

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def create
    transaction_date = Date::strptime(transaction_params, "%m/%d/%Y")
    outflow = params[:transaction][:outflow].include?(".") ? params[:transaction][:outflow].gsub(".", "").to_i : (params[:transaction][:outflow] + "00").to_i
    inflow = params[:transaction][:inflow].include?(".") ? params[:transaction][:inflow].gsub(".", "").to_i : (params[:transaction][:inflow] + "00").to_i

    @account = Account.find(params[:account][:id])
    @transaction = @transaction.new(transaction_params)

    @transaction.user_id = current_user.id    
    @transaction.account_id = @account.id
    @transaction.transaction_date = transaction_date
    @transaction.outflow = outflow
    @transaction.inflow = inflow
    @transaction.save


    diff = inflow - outflow
    new_account_balance = @account.balance + diff
    @account.update_attributes(balance: new_account_balance)
    redirect_to account_path(@account)
  end

  private
  def transaction_params
    params.require(:transaction).permit(:transaction_date, :payee, :account_id, :category, :memo, :inflow, :outflow, :user_id)
  end

end
```

**How do I reference the account_id in my controller?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would allow the params of the account as well. You can add {account_attributes: {:id}} to the transaction_params method and that will allow it. Then you can call transaction_params and get back the hash of params that you are free to modify as you please.

Comment: Better yet change the hidden_field_tag to :account_id and set its value not id. That will pass it in the form parameters. Then you can just allow account_id in the params.

Comment: I still haven't been able to figure it out. My hidden field is now : `= hidden_field_tag :account_id, value: params[:id]
` and my transaction_params logic is `params.require(:transaction).permit(:transaction_date, :payee, :account_id, :category, :memo, :inflow, :outflow, :user_id)`. When I puts my transaction_params, the account_id isn't there. Any tip?

Comment: You don't need to specify value: as the key. The second argument is the value. Do you have an association for the transaction to the account?